# Unable to change value of np element

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to change the value of an np array at a given index.

```
def mutate(child):
    if np.random.rand() < MUTATION_RATE:
        newgene = np.random.randint(low=1, high=98)
        randgene = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10)
        print(randgene)
        if newgene not in child:
            child[0][randgene] = newgene
        else:
            newgene = np.random.randint(low=1, high=98)
            child[0][randgene] = newgene
    else:
        child = child    
    child = np.sort(child)
    
    return child
```

So I would pass an array say, array([ 0,  3, 17, 42, 48, 51, 75, 76, 94, 99]), with shape (10,) but executing this method I get an error 'numpy.int32' object does not support item assignment

Comment: If it has shape (10,), then why are you indexing it with two dimensions?

Comment: @TimRoberts you're right lol, I looked at it again, I actually had mistakenly reshaped the array to be (1,10) instead of (10,)  which was why had done the 2d indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your access syntax is for a 2D array:

```
        child[0][randgene] = newgene
```

`child[0]` is `0`, the first element of your array.  `0[randgene]` is meaningless; for instance, what is the 3rd element of `0`?

Get rid of the `[0]` in your assignments:

```
import numpy as np
MUTATION_RATE = 0.3
def mutate(child):
    if np.random.rand() < MUTATION_RATE:
        newgene = np.random.randint(low=1, high=98)
        randgene = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10)
        print(randgene)
        if newgene not in child:
            child[randgene] = newgene
        else:
            newgene = np.random.randint(low=1, high=98)
            child[randgene] = newgene
    else:
        child = child    
    child = np.sort(child)
    
    return child

kid = np.array([ 0, 3, 17, 42, 48, 51, 75, 76, 94, 99])
print(kid)

print(mutate(kid))
```

Output:

```
[ 0  3 17 42 48 51 75 76 94 99]
5
[ 0  3 17 21 42 48 75 76 94 99]
```